# How can I mount from CentOS7 a drive shared from a home router using Samba?

Tags: linux, centos, mount, samba

I'm aiming to get a command line mount sorted out first,
then an (autofs?) fstab mount.

My HP printer (it's surely *nix inside), and my win computer both can use the drive,
but not my linux box.
[eg: I set up the printer - just through its gui - to write scans to it]

I can see the drive with smbclient but I can't mount it.

A few of the mount commands I've tried:

```
# mount -t cifs -o //192.168.1.1/USB_Storage      /mnt/netstore
# mount -t cifs -o //192.168.1.1/USB_Storage/adir /mnt/netstore credentials=/root/.smbcredentials
```

The most common result is:

```
# mount error(13): Permission denied
# Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

# echo $?
32
```

My goal is to connect to it and back it up on the linux box.

Details:
samba-client installed
cifs-utils   installed

```
# smbclient -L 192.168.1.1
```

prompts for "root's password"
and - as expected for the "no password" setting below - returns:

```
Domain=[CONSENSUS] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.13]
      Sharename       Type      Comment
      ---------       ----      -------
      USB_Storage     Disk      read:all-no password;write:all-no password
      IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (DocBak)
      ADMIN$          IPC       IPC Service (DocBak)

Domain=[CONSENSUS] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.13]
      Server               Comment
      ---------            -------
      DOCBAK               DocBak
      SONY7                My Laptop

      Workgroup            Master
      ---------            -------
      CONSENSUS            DOCBAK
```

Router GUI says:

```
Network/Device Name :   DocBak
Workgroup :             Consensus

Enable   Access Method       Link      Port
checked  Network Connection  \\DocBak  -

Available Network Folders
                       Read    Write
 Share Name            Access  Access  Folder Name  Volume Name
 \\DocBak\USB_Storage  All     All     U:\          USB_Storage
```

Server OS = CentOS 7.3
Client OS = Win10
Router = WNDR4000 (firmware: 1.0.2.4_9.1.86)
SELinux = enforcing

REF:
(main) http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SMB-HOWTO-8.html
(many others) ... still digging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mount succeeded after I put sec=ntlm in the empty -o (options) section

So from this one that wouldn't work:

```
# mount -t cifs -o          //192.168.1.1/USB_Storage /mnt/netstore
```

To this one that does:

```
# mount -t cifs -o sec=ntlm //192.168.1.1/USB_Storage /mnt/netstore
```

REF:
https://www.samba.org/~ab/output/htmldocs/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html
https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs

Comment: The REF link appears dead...

Comment: replaced the dead link